# How to set our own background image to facebook Login Button in xml?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

is it possible to set our own background image in xml for Facebook Login Button ?

my xmlc in my Project(i.e FBDemo)

> ```
> <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
>     xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/btn_login"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>     facebook:background_image="@drawable/login_with_fb"
>     facebook:confirm_logout="false"
>     facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />
> ```

I make changes in Facebook SDK like this

in FacebookSDK project
values/attr.xml

> ```
> <declare-styleable name="com_facebook_login_view">
>     <attr name="confirm_logout" format="boolean"/>
>     <attr name="fetch_user_info" format="boolean"/>
>     <attr name="login_text" format="string"/>
>     <attr name="logout_text" format="string"/>
>     <attr name="background_image" format="integer"/>
> </declare-styleable>
> ```

and in LoginButton.java

```
private int background_image;
private void parseAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view);
    confirmLogout = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_confirm_logout, true);
    fetchUserInfo = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_fetch_user_info, true);
    loginText = a.getString(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_login_text);
    logoutText = a.getString(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_logout_text);
    background_image = a.getInt(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_background_image, R.drawable.com_facebook_button_blue);

    a.recycle();
}

public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs.getStyleAttribute() == 0) {
        // apparently there's no method of setting a default style in xml,
        // so in case the users do not explicitly specify a style, we need
        // to use sensible defaults.
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_loginview_text_color));
        this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_text_size));
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            // cannot use a drawable in edit mode, so setting the background color instead
            // of a background resource.
            this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_blue));
            // hardcoding in edit mode as getResources().getString() doesn't seem to work in IntelliJ
            loginText = "Log in with Facebook";
        } else {
            //this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_blue);
            this.setBackgroundResource(background_image);
            this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.com_facebook_inverse_icon, 0, 0, 0);
            this.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_compound_drawable_padding));
            this.setPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_left),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_top),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_right),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_bottom));
        }
    }
    parseAttributes(attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        initializeActiveSessionWithCachedToken(context);
    }        
}
```

I am passing my own background to xml of Facebbok loginbutton in my xml

but this gives me runtime error like below

```
08-07 06:41:59.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-hdpi/login_with_fb.png"
```

I think this error occur because of login_with_fb.png image is reside in FBDemo and FacebookSDK project can't find drawable image login_with_fb.png in it

I know the other way, just setting background image in Activity , but I want to set in xml
is there any solution ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change below code in your Facebook SDK:Go to com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.java

```
 public LoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs.getStyleAttribute() == 0) {
        // apparently there's no method of setting a default style in xml,
        // so in case the users do not explicitly specify a style, we need
        // to use sensible defaults.
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_loginview_text_color));
        this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_text_size));
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            // cannot use a drawable in edit mode, so setting the background color instead
            // of a background resource.
//                      this.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_blue));
            // hardcoding in edit mode as getResources().getString() doesn't seem to work in IntelliJ
            loginText = "Log in with Facebook";
        } else {/*
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_blue);
            this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.com_facebook_inverse_icon, 0, 0, 0);
            this.setCompoundDrawablePadding(
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_compound_drawable_padding));
            this.setPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_left),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_top),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_right),
                    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.com_facebook_loginview_padding_bottom));
        */}
    }
    parseAttributes(attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        initializeActiveSessionWithCachedToken(context);
    }        
}
```

Also remove code from this method:

```
 private void setButtonText() {/*
    if (sessionTracker != null && sessionTracker.getOpenSession() != null) {
        setText((logoutText != null) ? logoutText :
                getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button));
    } else {
        setText((loginText != null) ? loginText :
                getResources().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button));
    }
*/}
```

Also comment below line from this method:

```
private void parseAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view);
    confirmLogout = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_confirm_logout, true);
    fetchUserInfo = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_fetch_user_info, true);
  /*  loginText = a.getString(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_login_text);
    logoutText = a.getString(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_logout_text);*/
    a.recycle();
}
```

And finally below code paste in your main activity code:

```
 loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));
    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            WelcomeActivity.this.user = user;
            updateUI();
        }
    });

    loginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_splash_fb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to change FB Login Button Background Image or text too?

for change its background image(not runtime)

1.copy your image to FB SDK's drawable-mdpi folder.

2.write this line in else mode (its not editmode)

```
this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourImageName);
```

3.and comment below line in code

```
    this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.com_facebook_inverse_icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

4.and in your xml

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/authButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/btn_login"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
facebook:background_image="@drawable/login_with_fb"
facebook:confirm_logout="false"
facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

Comment: That I already know and implemented , but I want to set image from my project, I don't want to copy image to Facebook SDK

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to default button and call facebook in onButtonClick.

Comment: I don't want to that default button and call facebook, 
Facebook giving the Button then why should I use default button